# не могу подать запрос на backend NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

очередной раз, не могу правильно написать запрос, и не могу понять в чем собственно дело. Вот мой код, и так же приведу скрин ошибки которую мне показывает.

```
$('#btn-reg').click(function() {
    alert('clicked')
    console.log($('#regUsername').val())
    console.log($('#regEmail').val())
    console.log($('#regPass').val())

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3000/api/register",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: {
        username: $("#regUsername").val(), 
        password: $("#regPassword").val(), 
        email: $("#regEmail").val()
      },
      complete: function() {
          //called when complete
          console.log('process complete');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('process sucess');
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('process error');
        console.log(status, error, xhr);
      }
    });

});
```

Вот snippet который предоставляет postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сама ошибка!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы зря рассчитываете, что `parseJSON` выполнит вызовы функций в JSON.

Comment: ... или что он будет использовать какие-то переменные, которые видны в этом месте (например, `$`).

Comment: @Igor тогда как мне лучше в этом случае поступить?

Comment: Пока не знаю ). Начать, наверное, надо с объяснения, какую цель Вы преследуете.

Comment: потому что без JSON.parse() данный пост запрос вызывает ошибку на сервере(

Comment: а с `JSON.parse()` - не вызывает?